# Faster method to update data in react than setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I am using react-chartjs-2 to display a trend line that is constantly updating. In order to set the values of the trend line, I am using the setState function of react, but I realized, that it takes about 40ms every time until the state is changed. Therefore I wanted to know, if there is a way to change the state faster, or to pass the data to the chart object without using the state of the component.

My code to update the state:

```
class CurveSection extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: { ... },
        options: { ... },
        startTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 0
    }


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.updateGraphs = this.updateGraphs.bind(this);
    }

    // updates graph data for CurveGraphs
    // called every 10 ms, but executed less frequently due to this.setState duration
    // therefore has to calculate each time how many values have to be updated in order to 
    // create a timematching graph
    updateGraphs() {
        var actualTime = new Date();
        var elementsToUpdate = Math.round((actualTime.getTime() - this.state.lastUpdateTime)/(1000/samplingFrequency) % numberOfValues)
        var queuePos = Math.round((actualTime.getTime() - this.state.startTime)/(1000/samplingFrequency) % numberOfValues)

        var dataCopy = this.state.data

        // doing stuff to data        

        this.setState({lastUpdateTime: actualTime.getTime(), data: dataCopy});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="CurveSection">
                <CurveGraph data={this.state.data.data1} options={this.state.options} />
                <CurveGraph data={this.state.data.data2} options={this.state.options} />
                <CurveGraph data={this.state.data.data3} options={this.state.options} />
                <CurveGraph data={this.state.data.data4} options={this.state.options} />
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you switch to another framework like [react-vis](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/)?

Comment: Could you also post how you are using `setState`?

Comment: I could switch to another framework, if it allows you to change the data faster ...